# Model.predict delays the real-time camera image

Tags: python, tf.keras

my project is real time monitoring with a live camera

Unfortunately, calling model.predict slows down the live image from the camera for a few seconds.
The Python Script runs on a Windows computer, CPU, 8 RAM

Is installed:
Python 3.7
Tensorflow 2.0.0
Kreas 2.2.4

At first I didn't know what would delay the picture so I got the line of code
model.predict commented out, then the live image is displayed in real time.

Does anyone have a tip?

Here is the code extract:

```
while True:
#USB Cam
frame = usbcam.read()
output = frame.copy()
trainbild = frame.copy()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   #Test, da bei training auch nicht umgewnadnetl
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224)).astype("float32") 
Q = deque(maxlen=args["size"]) #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224)).astype("float32") Original
frame -= mean

#make predictions on the frame and then update the predictions
#queue
preds = model.predict(np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0))[0]
Q.append(preds)

results = np.array(Q).mean(axis=0)
i = np.argmax(results)
label = classes[i]

text = "activity: {}".format(label)
cv2.putText(output, text, (35, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    1.25, (0, 255, 0), 5)
```

I have now installed everything for GPU use - I hope ;-)
The following error now occurs with preds = model.predict:

```
Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 25088), b.shape=(25088, 512), m=1, n=512, k=25088
 [[node model_1/dense_1/MatMul (defined at C:\PythonApplication1\envTensorflGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]]
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1544]  Function call stack: distributed_function
```

If I run the program on the CPU, this error does not come up.
Is there anything missing during the installation?

Comment: Do you have a Cuda enabled CPU and the tensorflow gpu version installed? It depends on the size/complexity of your model, how long predictions will take.

Comment: no, i have not installed the gpu version of tensorflow.
I thought this is only advisable if you have a GPU capable graphics card?
how can I check if my cpu Cuda is capable.

Comment: IMHO, you can Install the gpu version and tensorflow falls back to CPU if no Cuda enabled GPU is present. In the CMD execute `dxdiag` . This will list the details of your GPU. When its an Nvidia Card, Google the details of it. Btw, there are tensorflow functions to check if the GPU is available, but i cant remember them.

Comment: My laptop is a bit older
Graphics card NVIDIA GeForce 840M
In the information about graphics card:
NVIDIA CUDA 6.5.19 driver

Then should I try the TensorFlow GPU version?
Do I have to install additional drivers for the graphics card?

Comment: Use `multiprocessing` to read and preprocess the video. Pipeline processing and prediction.

Comment: I probably found the bug

 I was using CUDA 10.2
 I use upgrading to CUDA 10.0

Comment: maybe someone has an example of a Processing pipeline for predict? I have searched the internet for a few days now, but there are usually only examples to train new models. I have a hdf5 file as a model

will the predictive test really be faster with a pipeline?

Comment: I have now researched days on the internet, but I have not found an example of a live prediciton :-(
It's mostly about training a model, but that's not what I'm talking about.

does anyone have any idea / example how I can speed up the mode.predict call?